# Verificando se elemento é visível com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Preciso verificar o atributo `visibility` de uma `div`.

```
if ($('#divFiltros').css('visibility', 'visible').val() == true) {
    alert(true);
}
else {
    alert(false);
}
```

Como faço para verificar e entrar nesse `if` do exemplo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar tanto:

```
if(!$('.target').is(':hidden'))
```

como

```
if (!$('.target').css('visibility') == 'hidden'))
```

ou mesmo

```
if($('.target').is(':visible'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a função ().is do jQuery:

```
if ($('#divFiltros').is(":visible")) {
    alert(true);
}
else {
    alert(false);
}
```